# how to add a text view that is editable by users of the app?

Tags: android, textview, x-editable

How to add a text box in android studio that can be edited by users of the app? I have edited everything for the layout and what to add in the main activity of the program to make it runnable?

Comment: `... a text view that is editable ...` It's called an **EditText**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the EditText view component

Comment: but how to code in mainactivity.java to make the editText functional? Can you kindly teach me by giving little example